# AES encryption with CryptoJS corrupting unicode emoji

Tags: javascript, unicode, cryptojs

I'm writing a system, where a user can write something (via. mobile browser), and that "String" will be encrypted with a password, chosen by the user. Since unicode emojis are often used, they have to be supported too.

As lib for the crypto, I choose CryptoJs - so that the crypto can be done local on the devices.

Currently, when I encrypt a string, and decrypt the same sting, all emojis disappear/ are replaced with random chars.

```
var key = "123";
var content = "secret text with an emoji, ";

var encrypted = aes_encrypt(key, content); //U2FsdGVkX19IOHIt+eRkaOcmNuZrc1rkU7JepL4iNdUknzhDaLOnSjYBCklTktSe

var decrypted = aes_decrypt(key, encrypted);//secret text with an emoji, Ø<ß®
```

I'm using a pair of helper functions like this:

```
function aes_encrypt(key, content){
  var key_string = key + "";
  var content_string = ascii_to_hex(content) + "";
  var key_sha3 = sha3(key_string);
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content_string, key_sha3, {
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126});
  return encrypted + "";
};
```

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the crypto library you're using? The root issue here is that crypto algorithms operate on binary data, which JavaScript strings are not. Each character in a JavaScript string is two bytes. Crypto code that treats JavaScript strings as binary data usually ignore the higher byte, and assume the lower bytes are being used to store the data. Emoji require that higher byte whose data is being lost. You need to explicitly encode your string character data into UTF-8, in some form or another. A hacky solution would be to use encode/decodeURIComponent before/after decoding.

Comment: @JeremyBanks i'm using a copy of the original lib from google code (https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) .

Comment: Is aes_encrypt written by you?

Comment: yes, but it's only a small function, so i don't have to write it all everytime i'm encrypting sth.  `function aes_encrypt(key, content){`

    `var key_string = key + "";`
    `var content_string = ascii_to_hex(content) + "";`

    `var key_sha3 = sha3(key_string);`

 
  `var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content_string, key_sha3, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126});`
   `return encrypted + "";`
`};`

Comment: I don't see you applying an encoding - those are the correct bytes for , you just forgot to say which encoding to use for display.  is D83C + DFAE, which if treated as separate bytes D8, 3C, DF, AE and treated as ANSI constitute the four-character string `Ø<ß®`

Comment: That function's calling `ascii_to_hex`, but the content isn't ASCII-compatible, it's full unicode. This may be causing or reinforcing your issue, depending on how CryptoJS works. I again suggest trying `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` in order to produce an ASCII-compatible string. (The behaviour Mike observes makes me question the safety of CryptoJS's model -- I hope this isn't being used for something where real genuine security is required.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks thanks!! 
it works fine with these functions :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Warning:** It is extremely difficult to get cryptographic code right. It can be even harder in JavaScript, where you often lack control over the execution environment and (as discussed below) a lack of language support has led to inconsistent conventions. I have not done enough research about the CryptoJS library to know about its design or security, or whether it is being used safely in this context.
>
> Please do not rely on any of this code to be genuinely secure without a professional audit.

A common issue when working with cryptographic code in JavaScript has been that there was no built-in way to represent binary data. This has been resolved in modern engines (with types `Blobs` and `TypedArrays` in the browser and `Buffers` in Node.js), but there is still a lot code that doesn't take advantage of this for historical or compatibility reasons.

Without these built-in types, one common convention (used by the built-in [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) and [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) functions) is to use the built-in string type to hold binary data. A JavaScript string is really a list of two-byte values (usually containing UCS-2/UTF-16-encoded Unicode characters). Users wanting to store binary data will often just use the lower byte, ignoring the higher byte entirely.

If you're only handling ASCII-compatible data, you might get away with ignoring these details when using code like this (i.e. things will work -- but there may be subtle security consequences). This is because text encoded as ASCII looks the same as text encoded as UTF-16 with the high bytes stripped out. But when you venture beyond that, you need to do some encoding.

The most correct thing (aside from using a real binary type) to do would be to take the input string of characters, encode it to UTF-8, and put that data in the lower bytes of an output string. However, JavaScript doesn't provide a built-in function to do that. As a crude but simple alternative, [the `encodeURIComponent` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) will encode any valid unicode string into a UTF-8 based representation of entirely URL-safe characters, which are all ASCII-compatible. In the case of your code, that would mean something like this:

```
var key = "123";
var content = "secret text with an emoji, ";

var encrypted = aes_encrypt(key, encodeURIComponent(content));

var decrypted = decodeURIComponent(aes_decrypt(key, encrypted));
```

If you have a lot of non-URL-safe characters, this could result in the encoded data being much larger than necessary, but it should be safe. Also, `encodeURIComponent` will apparently throw an error for strings that contain "unpaired surrogate characters". I don't think these should occur in ordinary input, but someone could craft them.

I expect that there is a more-correct way to handle things like this in CryptoJS, but I am unaware of it.  Please consider looking into this further if you're planning to deploy this code for public use.

Comment: This is a quick, rough answer, but I felt it was better to have something here than leaving information scattered through the comments. I am not a cryptography expert, this is not reliable cryptography advice, <insert a dozen more disclaimers here, please consult an expert>, etc.

Comment: a) There really is no need for `encodeURIComponent`, because CryptoJS is capable of handling UTF-8 itself. b) The increase in size is negligible since OP is already doubling the size with `ascii_to_hex()`. c) You're right, getting crypto right is hard. I mostly give textual descriptions (and links) of what needs to be done instead of showing the appropriate code, because it would explode the post length.

Answer (score 3):

CryptoJS is capable of converting a UTF-8 encoded string to its own binary data format (`WordArray`). This can be accomplished with `var binData = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(string);`:

```js
var password = "123";
var content = "secret text with an emoji, ";

inContent.innerHTML = content;

var encrypted = aes_encrypt(password, content);
var decrypted = aes_decrypt(password, encrypted);

out.innerHTML = decrypted;

function aes_encrypt(password, content) {
  return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content, password).toString();
}

function aes_decrypt(password, encrypted) {
  return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

```css
#inContent { color: blue; }
#out { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<div>in: <span id="inContent"></span></div>
<div>out: <span id="out"></span></div>
```

This works because if a string is passed as content to `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` then it will be automatically parsed as UTF-8, but you need to convert it back to UTF-8 after decryption yourself. This is done with `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`.

---

This code only demonstrates that CryptoJS handles UTF-8 already very well. This is not secure, because

- MD5 with a single iteration is used for key derivation from the password. You would need to use something like PBKDF2, which CryptoJS provides. (Don't forget to use a random IV every time. It doesn't have to be secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext.)
- The ciphertext is not authenticated, which makes it unlikely to detect (malicious) manipulation of the encrypted data. It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256, which CryptoJS provides.

Comment: Thanks for the more informed explanation!